# Conversion from an .avsc file to a Java file using Maven

Tags: datetime, long-integer, avro, avsc

I created a `.avsc` file and I declared the following field: `{ "name": "event_time", "type": { "type" : "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}, "doc": "The timestamp when the event was registered." }`

When the `package` instruction from `maven` is executed, the following field is created: `private DateTime event_time;`

Then, the conversion from `DateTime` to `Long` is realized using the following code:

```
this.event_time = (DateTime)value$;
```

This line of code throws an exception when it is executed because the `Long` object cannot be converted into a `DateTime` object in this manner.

I would like to know if it is possible to rewrite the class which is generated from the `.avsc` file using the command `package`. This class is in the `target` folder.

Otherwise I would like to know what other possible options exist for sending a timestamp using AVRO.